# How to detect when a day in a jsp Calendar is clicked (selected) and do some action?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, calendar, stripes

I was searching for a way to update some variable in the Stripes Action (say it selectedDate) when a user clicks a specific date(lets say 11/15/2011) I wanted selectedDate to be updated (may be by binding the field with the selected day) and the page to be refreshed or displayed again. I might consider using ajax (instead of refreshing the page) for this purpose in the future.

If possible, I would like to create a method (that may return a Resoulution) in the ActionBean to display the page again.

FYI: I couldn't decide between `<calendar:calendars>` and `<tags:calendarWidget>`. I will consider the simplest one for now. Give me your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *selectedDate* field is on an non Ajax HTML form, then the Stripes Action is only executed when you submit/post the form to the server. If you want this form submit to happen automatically when the *selectedDate* field is changed, you need to add some Javascript code to your page. For example:

```
<stripes:text name="selectedDate" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
```

In case you use JQuery you might want to checkout:

[How to convert onchange="this.form.submit()" to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244564/how-to-convert-onchange-this-form-submit-to-jquery)

Comment: Thank you. Its seems like this what I was looking for. Even if I know these methods, I never considered them in my mind. I was thinking complicated things like, passing the date to another jSP page as a parameter ...bla bla. 

I have dome as u said and it works fine but, when the calendar changes the page didn't submit the form. I have to focus on the text filed and then lose focus (may be change the date). That is the time it submits the form. But I don't wanna do that. Why is that happening and what is the solution?

Comment: Thats happening because when loss focus after changing the value, it calls onchange.. just remove "this.form.submit()" <stripes:text name="selectedDate" onchange="do_something();"/>
function do_something(){/* do something */ }

Comment: Indeed, I kind of forgot how limited the onchange hook really is. If you are using JQuery you have more hooks that might help you. I don’t know what calendar code you use, but it might also provide you with hooks that let you call the form submit code...

Comment: First of all, when I changed the date from the calendar, it is not calling the onchange method. But, if I change the value manually and lose focus it fires the onchange method ... So I am confused why it is not calling the onchange method whn I change the day (which inturn changes the value in the textbox)?

Comment: As you noticed, the onchange is only fired when the value is changed AND the field looses focus. That's unfortunately the correct behavior of the onchange. But what you want can be implemented in Javascript libraries like JQuery (see link).

Answer (score 0):

```
when date picker would update an html element with the selected date.
call a function on onchange event of that element;
like

<input type="text" value="from date picker" onchange="update_date(this.value);">

function update_date(selecteDate){
if(selectedDate === "11/15/2011")
//do your need
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You can see my comment on the above answer. You might help.